# SKSpriteNode is gigantic

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

What am I doing wrong here?

```
let bgImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background.png")
var alloment1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "startingPatch.png")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    bgImage.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), CGRectGetMidX(self.frame))
    self.addChild(bgImage)


    alloment1.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), CGRectGetMidX(self.frame))
    self.addChild(alloment1)
}
```

I have this set up in my GameScene.swift file. I have no clue what could be going on. My background png is 1920x1080px(which is the resolution for 6+) and the image I want to be on the screen is 180px

Edit:[Image of what is happened!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2FIb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the dimensions of the iPhone 6+ are 1920x1080px. XCode uses points instead of pixels for coding so that apps can be at least somewhat compatible with all of apples devices. The 6+ is 3X dense so in order to get the point density, divide the boundaries by 3(640 x 360).

All you have to do is scale each image down using the `xScale` and `yScale`properties like so.

```
let bgImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background.png")
var alloment1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "startingPatch.png")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
bgImage.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidY(self.frame),     CGRectGetMidX(self.frame))
bgImage.xScale = 0.333
bgImage.yScale = 0.333
self.addChild(bgImage)



alloment1.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidY(self.frame), CGRectGetMidX(self.frame))
alloment1.xScale = 0.333
alloment1.yScale = 0.333
self.addChild(alloment1)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work... I am not quite sure what to do... I have updated the main thread to show what is happening. @Brennan Adler

Comment: Fortunatly it works when I change the code to something like `alloment1.xScale = 0.001`

Comment: So essentially this exact thing happened to me, when you create the scene in your ViewController add this line of code before the  `presentScene` function, `(sceneName).size = skView.bounds.size

Comment: Perfect! I forgot to add `let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)` Thank you very much! @Brennan Adler